# BGE. Is it possible to create transparent plane with blur filter?

Tags: python, game-engine, 3d-view

### 17 09 2015

here is blend to test: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/cwpyem6zve6r2u4/blur5.blend

---

I'm still trying to figure out **how to add blur** filter to plane to make under plane objects all blurred **in** **BGE**.
Here is very final result I want to see:
[image]

I just found old script to make portals. And it still works, but it seems to be buggy sometimes, it's look like a *true*(fake) glass.
**All i need** to do **is** to add **gaussian blur filter to glass plane**. (I marked this area blue color background - **this area objects under plane needs to be blurred**.)
[image]
Here is .blend to improve: **[blend file here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8c68m6uo4mv69x5/blur_window0.02.blend)**

Need any suggestions and solutions...
Thanks for helping!!! :)

---

Comment: I think you mean frosted glass, maybe this video could help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvEC8UNlgJg :)

Comment: No not Blender cycles, I want to see it in BGE.

Comment: @PrivacyGoth If you found an answer please don't wirite solved! on the question,  write an answer instead detailing how you solved it. so that others can learn as well.

Comment: @cegaton why this site seeking for all users, and makes all feeling disscomforted? For ex: me. ?

Comment: @PrivacyGoth I'm sorry you are feeling like that. This site is run by people who like to use blender and volunteer their time and knowledge to  help others. It's collectively moderated by the users themselves and has a few appointed moderators to resolve larger issues. It is a question and answer site, not a forum. Please read this for more info: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour For a more relaxed way to use the site use the chat section http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm .To bring up issues use Meta: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also look at the help center to undestand how to make better use of the site. http://blender.stackexchange.com/help :)

Comment: [I made a frosted glass in UPBGE 2.79](https://mega.nz/file/fIIWTZrR#A545WZXZmhMF7TtA29V-4Sk2uj9y8ilpWdX-ir6dub0)

Answer (score 2):

I never used BGE and you blend file link gives a 403, but here's how I'd implement that effect:

**Normally in a game engine:**

Render your scene to a texture. That's the first step you normally do for post-processing.

Render the glass pane to another texture. The glass pane should be white, the rest black. Disable material and light for faster rendering. If your glass pane is partially hidden by other objects, these parts should also be black in your rendering.

Blur your original rendering. Use the black/white texture as a mask so only the glass pane gets blurred. Alternatively, blur the whole image in a copy and use the texture to combine both.

**In Blender:**
[image: Node setup]
Here's my node setup with an exaggerated version of the effect. On the right, the blur map. I used the object ID pass to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the post draw callbacks and pyopengl to draw onto the screen,

so I think*

1. you can grab the *view* of the plane using a camera render to
   texture
2. then operate on the texture *blur*
3. use pyopengl to draw a plane over the old plane with the new texture?